# Is it possible to blur only specific part of the image using CSS filter ?

Tags: css

I have a background image and want to blur a specific part of it without effecting the whole image ? For instance, only bottom left side corner, center or top right side corner ? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: What is your actual objective? Are you trying to hide information (because client-side blurring will not help with that) or just help the user focus on one part of the image?

Comment: check these: https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/ && http://jordanhollinger.com/2014/01/29/css-gaussian-blur-behind-a-translucent-box/ && https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/ && https://css-tricks.com/blurry-background-effect/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, using only `CSS` can't make this happen. You can acheive your goal through putting an extra `absolute` element in the same container that contains your background image.

Probably something like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function(e) {
    $(".blurry").css('background-color', 'white')
      .css('opacity', '.7')
      .css('box-shadow', 'white 0px 0px 20px 20px');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width:500px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;  
}

#brand {
  width:500px;
  height:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeQzt.jpg?s=328&g=1");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.blurry {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  left:30px;
  bottom:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a id="brand"></a>
    <div class="blurry"></div>
  </div>  
</div>

<button>blur</button>
```