# How to blur a background image from a particular point to bottom using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have to blur only the bottom half portion of a background image. It should be like,

[image]

This code blurs the whole image:

```
<style>
body {
  background-image: url('ms.png');
  background-size:100% auto;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
</style>
```

How to do it using CSS?

Comment: The best option would be to absolutely position another element inside your background container. Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470204/is-it-possible-to-blur-only-specific-part-of-the-image-using-css-filter

Comment: Here is another example of a similar question asked previously [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265041/blur-part-of-an-image-with-css)

Comment: Yeah, that works for me.